# Bogus NDK stack backtrace after upgrading to Crashlytics NDK 2.+

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-fabric

Looking for fabric support on an unwinding issue in the NDK stack trace after migrating from Crashlytics (2.6.8)/Crashlytics NDK (1.1.5) to Crashlytics (2.8.0)/Crashlytics NDK (2.0.0) and any newer versions after that. The stack trace we get prior to upgrading the libraries looked OK but after there a lot of missing symbols and the addresses jump wildly within and outside the application libraries. We've seen addresses jump hundreds of megabytes in address space from one frame to the next.

So far we've verified the issue is caused by changing the version strings in the .gradle file--there were no other changes. Furthermore, we believe the cSYM files are being generated correctly and in fact, the gradle build tools for Fabric is 1.26.1 for all builds. The upload process to Fabric is working fine too.

This issue is similar to [Invalid NDK crash backtraces on ARM/ARM64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765265/invalid-ndk-crash-backtraces-on-arm-arm64/52902502#52902502) but the missing symbols and bogus trace happens on the same builds with ARM and x86 was not tested.