# Fabric Crashlytics NDK stack backtraces missing frames

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics-android

I have an Android Studio project that includes multiple native shared libraries.

I followed the steps documented here to integrate Crashlytics NDK support and upload symbols to Fabric:
https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk

The crashes are successfully reported:

```
D/CrashlyticsCore: Checking for crash reports...
D/CrashlyticsCore: Attempting to send 1 report(s)
D/CrashlyticsCore: Sending report to: ...
D/CrashlyticsCore: Result was: 202
I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete:
```

and I do see them in the Fabric Crashlytics console.

However, I am seeing the following problems in the backtraces:

1. There are missing frames. Oftentimes only one frame shows symbols from my native libraries (usually just the frame that caused the crash).
2. The frames don't always seem to make sense. For example, between direct function calls there will be 'ghost' frames with no symbols.
3. Missing symbols from libc.so

Here's an example:

```
#0
Crashed: Thread
SIGABRT 0x00000000000008b1

Crashed: Thread
0  libc.so                        0xf5465d66 (Missing)
1  libc.so                        0xf54a4665 (Missing)
2  libc.so                        0xf5465fe1 (Missing)
3  libMyLibrary.so                0xd9e79622 (Missing)
4  libMyLibrary.so                0xd9c23d83 Java_com_xxxxxxxx (MySource.cpp:109)
5  (Missing)                      0x705e92cc (Missing)
6  (Missing)                      0xdb84aa3a (Missing)
7  (Missing)                      0xf4645d9e (Missing)
8  libart.so                      0xf37eacb7 (Missing)
9  (Missing)                      0x136b8b36 (Missing)
10 (Missing)                      0xdb84aa32 (Missing)
<frames omitted for brevity, all with missing symbols>
62 libart.so                      0xf3a13ece (Missing)
63 libart.so                      0xf3800caf (Missing)
64 (Missing)                      0x13001756 (Missing)
```

Frame 3 is missing symbols. Also, there should have been other frames in my native lib following frame 4 but those are missing details.

I am using crashlytics:2.9.8 and crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5

Possibly related to [Bogus NDK stack backtrace after upgrading to Crashlytics NDK 2.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908673/bogus-ndk-stack-backtrace-after-upgrading-to-crashlytics-ndk-2)

Any suggestions? Is there an issue with crashlytics-ndk-2.x?

Comment: were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: No. I have since abandoned Fabric/Crashlytics. The Google Console provides better stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, I was experiencing the same thing. I was only syncing the active variant which was debug for me so I synced all release builds and then built, re ran crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease in the terminal and after that I started seeing the native method names when the app crashed